# Using Pipe with FormControlName in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an angular 7 app. And I have a form like below. I create a pipe. And it's  working  perfectly. But, when I use by `formControlName` like below stackblitz, it give me error. How can I achieve this?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwg9vp)

Comment: You cannot use pipe in the `formControlName`

Comment: But, I need to change my value after value come from server. How can I achieve this? @SachinGupta

Comment: @HasanOzdemir, What is your actual requirement?? Do you want the value of ```1,234,567.00``` needs to set to the input box?? Is this is your requirement https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcejna ??

Comment: I want when I clicked save button, it log to console {myNumber: "1,234,567.00"} @ManirajfromKarur  .Because, in real life scenario, I will use for Datetime. And I will send datetime as string to server because of timezone problem.

Comment: In your stackblitz example, when I enter some number to TextBox, it gave me {myNumber: "1,234,999.00"}. It worked perfectly. But, when I click directly save button, then it gave me {myNumber: 1234567}. If, we can achieve, when directly click {myNumber: "1,234,567.00"}, then I will reach my purpose. @ManirajfromKarur

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Have added an answer have a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pipe in ts file if you want to perform the transformation logic in the component.ts:

TS code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

import { InputConverterPipe } from './input-converter.pipe'; // Import the pipe

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [InputConverterPipe]   // Add in providers array
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public InputConverterPipe: InputConverterPipe) { }

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    myNumber: [1234567],
  });

  save() {
    var convertedString = this.InputConverterPipe.transform(this.myForm.value.myNumber);
    console.log(convertedString);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aotbtm)

Comment: Thanks @PrashantPimpale. Using in save method isn't possible in my real scenario. This stackblitz example working fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pemru8 . But only missing thing is if user directly click 'save' button, then console write 1234567 . But, if user write to input something, it's working perfectly. So, can I do something like this `<input init="trigger()"` on input init for trigger and set my value ?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir You can test it when I directly click on save button it prints expected one

Comment: Yes,I know your example will work. But, I don't write code in my `save` method. Because in my real application there will be a lot of input and pipes. So, I'm looking for generic solution. I said that for not working for this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pemru8 link. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @HasanOzdemir its only single liner! but at the end it depends on you!

Comment: In my real scenario, I will write for datetime because of timezone problem. So, if any people in my team forget writing that line, then it will be created incorrect data in my database. So, I need to generic solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here the pipe inside the Input `formControlName` was not possible and i have made the things into `TS`..

Changes i would like to make in your code was,

Include your InputConverterPipe in Providers array in `app.module.ts`,

```
providers: [InputConverterPipe]
```

Then import it in your `app.component.ts`,

```
import { InputConverterPipe } from './input-converter.pipe';
```

And inject it inside constructor,

```
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private inputConverterPipe: InputConverterPipe) { }
```

And in your save function make the `console.log` changes like this,

```
  save() {
    let getFormattedNumber = this.inputConverterPipe.transform(this.myForm.get('myNumber').value);
    console.log(getFormattedNumber);
  }
```

And working **stackblitz** here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcejna ..

Comment: Thanks @ManirajfromKarur. Your first stackblitz is very appropriate to my purpose. But there was only problem in that is ,when directly click Save button.Because if people change input value, then your first stackblitz working perfectly. Is there any possibility of like this `<input init="trigger()` >. The other saying, can I trigger and set my converted value on input created.